# How to deal with memory fragmentation in Vulkan

Tags: vulkan

First of all, please don't tell me to use VMA.

Okay so here is my issue, I'm writing a game engine with Vulkan, and I've just written all the code needed to add meshes to my scenes. That's not a problem at all, the problem comes when deleting meshes.

Because Vulkan has some pretty hardcore memory limitations, for example, the maximum number of memory allocations, I've decided that the way that I'm going to allocate memory is with "blocks". So basically, I just allocate a big block of memory, say, 128 or 256MB, and when that block is full, I just allocate another one. But for the sake of not overcomplicating the question, lets assume that I'll only have one block in the entire lifespan of my program, which I'm going to represent like this:

```
__________________________________________________________________
|                                                                |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Lets say that start adding meshes to my block...

```
__________________________________________________________________
|OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO                |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

That's all well and good, but now let us delete a mesh in the middle of the block...

```
__________________________________________________________________
|OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO       OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO                |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In this situation there are two options that come to my mind:

1. **Freelist**: Every time I delete a mesh, I add the range (offset and size) of the deleted mesh to a list, and then when I have to render everything, I just skip that section. So basically, a freelist. The pros of this approach are: 1. No additional memory allocations. 2. No transfer operations. And the cons is just that when I've deleted a bunch of meshes, I'll end up with a lot of memory fragmentation.
2. **Vector**: When I delete a mesh, I allocate a new block, and I perform the transfer operation required to leave the memory with no gaps, basically, just like `std::vector.erase()` works (although `std::vector` doesn't allocate new memory, but because it moves the elements one by one to the left, I need to move everything at once through a Vulkan transfer operation):

.

```
__________________________________________________________________
|OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO       OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO                |
------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                    |      /                  /
 |                    |     /                  /
 |                    |    /                  /
 |                    |   /                  /
 |                    |  /                  /
 |                    | /                  /
 |                    |/                  /
__________________________________________________________________
|OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO                       |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The pros of this is no memory fragmentation at all. The cons are: 1. One memory allocation. 2. The transfer operation.

With the first approach, I could also write a function that defragments the block with a transfer operation similar to the one described in approach 2, but with multiple ranges (multiple `VkBufferCopy` structures), and then call that function when there is a lot of memory gaps. Also, when I restart the program, the meshes would be added in order, so the problem would be solved by just restarting the engine.

With the second approach, when you have a lot of memory to transfer, it may produce a bit of a stutter in you program, maybe an FPS drop. Which could be reduced maybe by performing the transfer operation on a separate asynchronous transfer queue, from a queue family the only supports transfer operations, so that I uses the DMA engine of you GPU. Is this a thing or am I tripping?

What do you think is the best approach for this?

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Comment: "*the maximum number of memory allocations*" That's not an especially hardcore limitation. Indeed, the *entire point* of it is to stop you from doing the thing that you were *clearly* going to do: make Vulkan allocations for every individual thing. So it worked.

Comment: Copy whatever VMA does, and use that then. This is not a question but a topic for a book.

Comment: "*The cons are: 1. One memory allocation. 2. The transfer operation.*" There are (or can be) *way more* "cons" than that. If any of those things are textures, you can't just shift them down. You must first create new `VkImage` objects at the destination and copy into them individually. And if they overlap, then you're out of luck.

Comment: @krOoze: "*Copy whatever VMA does, and use that then.*" I wouldn't call VMA a good general solution for this.

Comment: "*What do you think is the best approach for this?*" The problem with this question is that it's essentially unanswerable. The right answer depends on what your program is doing *exactly*. There isn't a one-size-fits-all answer, and that's kind of the point of APIs like Vulkan: they allow you to code for your specific circumstances.

Comment: @NicolBolas Solution for what? There was no problem statement given.

Comment: @NicolBolas Think of when you add objects to a scene in Unreal or any other game engine, and then start deleting some.

Comment: @Karlos: OK, but... why are you adding objects to memory? Why are you deleting them from memory? Is there any correlation between groups of objects and this addition/removal? Are we doing a level load/unload; if so, are some models preserved through this process? Are we streaming level geometry, such that old geometry goes away and new geometry appears? *All* of these questions change the nature of how you would most efficiently allocate memory. You can try to build a one-size-fits-all solution, but it will never be the most efficient.

Comment: @NicolBolas I was just thinking of when you are trying to build a level, and you add meshes to your vertex/index buffers from disk, but of course one would want to delete those objects from the level editor at any time...

Comment: @Karlos: Why do you care if your *level editor* has a 20 millisecond hitch in it?

Comment: @NicolBolas Idk, I'm just trying to find the best way of dealing with such cases.